Partial upgrade to 24.04.1 broke shared libraries
while upgrading my 22.04 ubuntu to the new 24.04.1 release, my computer was hard rebooted (oops). My shared libraries, specifically libgio2.0 and libglib2.0, are now broken, and I have no internet now (NetworkManager is crashing and I have to boot into recovery mode).
In my journalctl I see:
NetworkManager[1361]: /usr/sbin/NetworkManager: error while loading shared libraries: libgio-2.0.so.0

and trying to run netplan results in
OSError: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However, running ldconfig -p | grep -i libglib shows that a 32-bit version of that specific file can be found at /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0? libgio2.0 can also be found in that directory.
How would I go about solving this issue?
Here are some (literal) screenshots of the issue: https://imgur.com/a/4CPdGDL

Reinstall a fresh copy of Ubuntu 24.04.1. Of course you backed up your data before you started the upgrade.

This may help re-enable networking: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1f72hul/dns_resolver_seems_to_stop_working_mid_upgrade_to/?share_id=Doy3YYlj8x3IBWsjVlciv&utm_content=1&utm_medium=android_app&utm_name=androidcss&utm_source=share&utm_term=1

OK doing a simple and dumb thing worked! I had a working WSL install of ubuntu, and I simply copied the .so files from /lib/x86_linux_gnu over to the broken system!
I needed to copy libgobject-2.0, libgio-2.0, libglib-2.0, and libgmodule-2.0
After running ldcofing, I was able to start NetworkManager and fix my system.
